# native japanese do not use desu or masu at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I recognized that native japanese speaker do not use desu or masu at the end of their sentences. Just in a few cases they do.

But all of my trainigs use the postfix.
Are there additional rules for that?

Thanks

Comment: Hello 'FooBar', I'm not sure what kind of materials you're using to study, but i'm sure that at early stages you'll learn on it that "masu" is not a must to create a sentence in Japanese.

Comment: Have you learned about the roles that です and ます play in Japanese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native speakers do actually use ます and です, however it depends on the situation. In situations at work where you are talking with clients or your higher ups, you would definitely use these, along with 敬語 (けいご aka formal speaking). Times when you talk with family, friends, and other more informal situations you may not need to use these forms and may use slang as well as informal speaking. By gender, men (and children) also tend to speak less formally than women do, even when in the same social situation, tho that depends on the individual.

It's somewhat similar in English. If you think of formal speech you may say:
"I am going to go to the store, do you want me to pick something up for you?"

But informal will likely sound more like:
"I'm gonna run to the store real quick, you want somethin'?"

Or even:
"I'mma hop over to the store, whatcha wanna get?"

In Japanese it's a bit more complex, because grammar and conjugations play a big role in varying degrees of formality, but the general idea is the same.